# Missing few Google Analytics e-commerce transactions

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

In Google Analytics e-commerce View there is missing some transactions (the oldest given that is missing is of 11.02.2019), don't have access to that google account(its a client account). So made some tests where send to my Google Analytic test account where receive well the transaction but some times seems does not apear but may take some time as documentation explains, so is there a way to test by the id of the transaction to see if google analytic is still processing, what is max time possible before showing a transaction in view, is it normal/possible that some transaction fail to receive or sent???

the code to send the transaction and items associated:

```
ga('ecommerce:clear');

ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {
    'id': ''+docIDFinal,
    'revenue': ''+parseFloat($('#total_Price_w_port').text().replace(',','.')),  
    'shipping': ''+parseFloat($('#port_total').text().replace(',','.')),  
    'currency': 'EUR'  
});                                                          

$('#table_product tbody tr').each(function(index){
    if(index==0)
            return true;
    ga('ecommerce:addItem', {
        'id': ''+DocItemsIDS[index],          
        'name': ''+$(this).find('td[data-th="Produto"]').text(),   
        'sku': ''+$(this).attr('type'), 
        'price': ''+parseFloat($(this).find('td[data-th="Sub-Total"] strong.subvalue').attr('unitprice').replace(',','.')), 
        'quantity': ''+$(this).find('td[data-th="Quantidade"] label').text(), 
        'currency': 'EUR'  
    });                                                                  
});             


ga('ecommerce:send');
```

Answer (score 0):

> so is there a way to test by the id of the transaction to see if google analytic is still processing

No, there is no way to see if specific hits are still processing. Depending on a number of factors, it could take over a day to show up in your analytics reporting.

Looking at your code, there doesn't appear to be anything monstrously wrong, but it is heavy on site scraping. The risk with site scraping is that given the plethora of browsers and devices, I have found it very unreliable. One client I had, I was able to increase captured transactions by 4000bp by removing all the scraping code. It would be ideal if the ecom platform produced a clean object similar to:

```
window.transactionLayer = {
  id: "ABCD",
  amount: 100.00,
  currency: 'EUR',
  products: [...],
  ....
}
```

Then consume those JS variables in your analytics push.

In addition, there are many reasons a transaction might not appear in your view:

- Ad blocker prevented GA tracking from firing
- JS error in your code for edge case prevented fire
- Filtering on your view in GA to exclude hits from XXX
- Network issues for delivery of the hit to Google

Answer (score 0):

Another reason that transactions fail to process is if you've exceeded your hit limits, which are:

500 per User session, or
200,000 per User per day

If you're tracking product impressions this can easily be eaten up and any GA hits (anytime you send data to GA) after this will not be processed.

This can be tricky to isolate as it fails silently.